# Tomcat Logging Conflict

Tags: java, tomcat, logging, log4j

I am using Tomcat 5.5 with a web-app that consists of "plug-ins".

One of the plug-ins depend on a jar library that makes use of log4j.

When I deploy the jar with log4j it seems that Tomcat starts relying on log4j for logging.

The jars are placed in `WEB-INF/lib`.

I want to separate the logging in order for tomcat to use the standard logging and the plugin its own logging.(log4j)

How can I tell Tomcat to ignore log4j?

Is there more to it?

Comment: What do you mean by "standard logging"?  Are you talking about the log files in the "TOMCAT/logs" directory?  I don't think log4j interferes with that.

Comment: Yes, after I include the libearies all output is send to a single file (the jar library l4j).

Comment: You can change the location of the file that log4j writes to.  See the "Configuration" section of this page: http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/manual.html

Comment: We want to avoid doing that. :-(

Comment: I would look more into the topic of log4j configuration.  It's likely that you'll be able to achieve the results you're looking for by configuring log4j.properties properly.

Comment: The thing is that I cannot use log4j at all. I know its not ideal but I have to conform to the way things currently work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We were able to convince the vendor to provide a Logging driver configuration that allows one to not use log4j and specify ones own logging driver.